# Control JavaSE application remotely using a web page

Tags: java, php, sockets, remote-access

I am designing a JavaSE application that uses the webcam as an IP Cam.
This application has 2 modes

i. Live video stream

ii. Motion Detection Image Capture (When motion is detected it captures a frame and stores it)

I implemented this using JavaCV libraries.

How can I build a web interface to remotely switch between these two modes. And display the Video or Image on the web page.

Also how can I stream the live video to the webpage.

I plan on using PHP.

Any help would be appreciated. I wouldnt mind any links or tutorials.

Comment: you may want to check and see what features your cam has available out of the box. Embedded web server could be one of them. See if and how that could play into your plans

Comment: Its a laptop integrated webcam and it does not have any special features that may be useful...

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 opinions

First you run the Webserver inside the Java Application (this causes no php)

Pros:

- User Friendly
- Simple if you use an embedded Servlet Container or similar like the Velocity processor

Cons:

- Not easy to access from outside the network

Second you run a webserver somewhere in the internet and the Java Application Streams the Video to the Server

Pros:

- Easy to access from the outside
- PHP available

Cons:

- You need to implement to things

For the streaming part, I have no good idea at the moment - maybe try something like vlcj.